# Google shared contact API for python

Tags: python, google-contacts-api

I would like to use python to add/update external contacts that are shared to all users in a g suite domain and I'm having issue trying to figure out how. Looking at documents in https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3, looks like the process involves Google sign-in, however in the app I'm working on I don't want user to provide creds/sign in to Google, all authorization process will be done on server side.

This is my current code I'm using to get users' contact, and I'm wondering if it is possible to do anything similar to get/add/update external contacts using service account/p12 keys:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
 SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
 P12_FILE_PATH,
 KEY_SECRET,
 scopes=[
 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'
 ]
)

credentials = credentials.create_delegated(SUPER_ADMIN_EMAIL)
admin = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)

admin.users().get(userKey=user_email).execute()
```

Thanks

Comment: This might be off-topic.